# Getting value from multiple select in LIstbox ZK

Tags: java, web-applications, zk

i want to ask about getting value from multiple select in Listbox, i have code in zul like this:

```
<n:tr>
                <n:td>
                    <label value="Privilege"/>
                </n:td>
                <n:td>
                    <label value=""/>
                </n:td>
                <n:td>
                     <listbox id="designations" model="@{addUser$composer.lstPrivilege}" selectedItem="@{selectedUserAcc, converter=com.nsia.doku.escrow.converter.SelectedItemConverter}" multiple="true" checkmark="true" width="200px">
                                <listitem self="@{each=lstPrivilege}" >
                                    <listcell label="@{lstPrivilege.description}"/>
                                </listitem>
                     </listbox>
                </n:td>
            </n:tr>
            <n:tr>
                <n:td>

                </n:td>
                <n:td>

                </n:td>
                <n:td>
                     <button label="Submit" onClick='
                     import com.dokuescrow.dto.Activity;
                     ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
                        for (Activity li : selectedUserAcc)
                        {
                            al.add(li.activityId);
                        }
                        alert(al);
                     '/>
                </n:td>
            </n:tr>
```

my problem is,how do i get the selected value in my controller class, i do test in my button using `onClick='..`,the value selectedUserAcc not null and like i want,if i pass the action in my controller class (eg. using method),the value i print out is null..anybody want to help me what is wrong with my class?

my method in controller is like this:

```
public void onClick$submit(Event event){
        try {

            ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
                        for (Activity li : selectedUserAcc)
                        {
                            al.add(li.getActivityId());
                        }
           alert(al.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

hope somebody can help me..thanks..:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK,after googling,searching,and trying (:D),i got answer for this question,the thing you must do is call the converter in your controller,the converter i got from ZK forum [here](http://www.zkoss.org/forum/listComment/7871/)
,and change the return to object,(bot return null),my prgram would be like this:

```
 SelectedItemConverter select=new SelectedItemConverter();

       for (Activity li : (Set<Activity>)select.coerceToBean(selectedUserAcc, getListGent()))
                        {
                            al.add(li);
                        }


                        List<Activity> act=al;
```

so i got my selected object i want..thanks for your attention..:D

`litGen` is my lisbox id